# Firebase database does not retrieve part of items

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I was testing my app on 2 emulators and 1 device. I've added 10 items from one emulator, 4 items from another one and 6 items from device.
As a result p0.childrenCount returns 10 on the first emulator, 14 on the second and 20 on device.
When I use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, I get 20 items on emulators and device.
Has anyone else faced this issue?
I started after updating to Firebase UI 2.0.1 and repeats in 2.1.0.
Emulators use API 24 and 26.

```
Ref.orderByChild("createTimeDesc").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                println(p0.childrenCount)
            }
        })
```

At the same time addValueEventListener seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I've tried to disable persistence and addListenerForSingleValueEvent returnd right ammount of items. When I enabled it, addListenerForSingleValueEvent returned wrong result.

```
public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase() {
        if (mDatabase == null) {
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(false);
        }
        return mDatabase;
    }
```